# URL redirect leads to file download in my web application + VirtualMin

Tags: ssl, redirect, lets-encrypt, webmin, virtualmin

Have `Letsencrypt SSL` installed in my ubuntu instance and SSL configured for one of my domains, but when i run it in browser(`https://example.com`), it is downloading a source code file. Why is this happening? What Change can I do thru virtual min to resolve this?

Comment: What kind of "source code file" are you refering to? Are you sure this is related to Lets Encrypt after all?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might or might not be in the part where you **also** configure SSL but it has nothing to do with SSL itself. If there would be a problem with SSL this would result in connectivity problems, handshake error, security warnings etc but not in showing the source code.

Comment: ok, i put SSL as i noticed it just after i renewed my Certs, but yeah it could be any other thing. Any idea on why this would be happening,

Comment: @clint: There are no useful information in your question which might help to find the cause of your problem. The amount of detail is comparable to asking somebody what is broken with your car and providing only the information that your car is red.

Comment: ok, what kind of information, you are looking for, tell me, i will give.

Comment: @clint: You need to provide your full configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Hello so that we can answer your question accurately and clearly. You need to send the log or the errors you are having on your terminal.

But beforehand, I advise you to remove let's encrypt and install it again. You do this in settings in the same part where you do the update.

And consult on the Virtualmin forum.

That should help ...

We look forward to your return, in case your solution is positive or not!